# Tomcat for multiple domains - How to retain domain name in address bar?

Tags: tomcat, dns, web, hosting

I have tomcat running in port 80 on VPS hosting (windows).

I created 2 applications 
http://localhost/test1
http://localhost/test2

Assume ip as 1.2.3.4

I own 2 domain names test1.com and test2.com

I asked my domain provider to map test1.com to 1.2.3.4/test1 and test2.com to 1.2.3.4/test2

They forwarded request to domain names to respective tomcat path. However when I browse my domain over internet as www.test1.com it gives me 1.2.3.4/test1 in address bar and my domain name disappears. How do I keep domain name in address bar for all my requests to tomcat.

I am unable to post URL due to stackflow restrictions. You can browse iocs.in to see the output.

Additional info: Except port changed to 80, no other change made in server.XML

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information for a definitive answer, but let me try my best guess: By "domain provider" you're referring to someone who is operating a webserver-redirect, and they do just what you've told them: Redirect a request to `test1.com` to `1.2.3.4/test1`.

You'll need an actual DNS entry pointing both domains to 1.2.3.4, then you can use [virtual hosting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) on tomcat, or better, introduce an Apache httpd that forwards to the tomcat instances.

As long as the DNS-record for your domains doesn't point to 1.2.3.4, you could also ask them to proxy requests for your domain: Their Webserver would act as test1.com but not hold any data, instead *it* would connect to 1.2.3.4 on behalf of the clients and forward any data it receives back to the clients.

Easiest way to figure out what DNS points to: just execute `ping test1.com`.

Comment: I resolved it by dealing with domain provider asking him to create A record for both domains and configured hosts accordingly.